# copy past object in python opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, paste, cut

I have this image 
[image]

i already have the contour of the bullet shape using

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

but now i would like to extract the bullet from the image and past it on another blank image, choosing the coordinates i would like. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use Grabcut algorithm to extract the forground image, here is some code that u will also like

```
img = cv2.imread('IMAGE.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (50,50,450,290)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

This might be little hazzy or not soo sharp , what u can do is apply a edge detection first to refine ur input and apply the above .